# Time until the next maximum?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, extreme-value-theorem, extreme-value-analysis

Suppose that every year we sample $n$ random variables from a normal distribution. We want to keep track of the maximum value. On average, what is the meantime arrival between the maxima for the first $t$ periods?

I'm guessing the expected arrival time increases with $t$.

Comment: It's likely the answer is trivial but I can't really tell.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but a sample is a *local* maximum with probability $\frac13$ (either of it and its two neighbours could be greatest), whereby the average distance between two local maxima is $3$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen What do you mean by local maxima? So you are saying that it's simply 1/t and independent of the sample?